# Select closest quantity in select form field

Tags: jquery

I have quantity selection input which gives a range of quantities.

I can select a value using jquery if the value (objRtn.numMultiPages) matches a data-qty value but i'm stuck if the quantity is between 2 breaks e.g. if I give it a quantity of 9 I would like it to select the upper value of 10, 23 would select 25 etc.

```
var selVal = $('#qtySelect').find("[data-qty='"+ objRtn.numMultiPages +"']").val();
if (selVal != undefined){
   $('#qtySelect').val(selVal);
   console.log(selVal);
} else {
   alert("too many pages");
}

<select name="qtySelect" id="qtySelect" class="form-control">
   <option class="qtyValue" value="14380" data-qty="5">Quantity: 5</option>
   <option class="qtyValue" value="14381" data-qty="10">Quantity: 10</option>
   <option class="qtyValue" value="14382" data-qty="15">Quantity: 15</option>
   <option class="qtyValue" value="14383" data-qty="25">Quantity: 25</option>
   <option class="qtyValue" value="14384" data-qty="50">Quantity: 50</option>
   <option class="qtyValue" value="14385" data-qty="100">Quantity: 100 </option>
</select>
```

Please can someone suggest a way to select the closest upper value?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var vals = -1;
$('#qtySelect').find("[data-qty]").each(function(i, el){
    if(objRtn.numMultiPages < $(el).data("qty") && vals === -1){
        vals = $(el).data("qty");
        return;
    }
});

var selVal = $('#qtySelect').find("[data-qty='"+ vals +"']").val();
if (selVal != undefined){
   $('#qtySelect').val(selVal);
   console.log(selVal);
} else {
   alert("too many pages");
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLFE6/

Answer (score 0):

Simple math;

```
var rounded_value = 5 * Math.round(objRtn.numMultiPages/5);
```

for upper values, you may check it yourself;

```
if (objRtn.numMultiPages > 25 && objRtn.numMultiPages < 50 ) {
     var rounded_value = 25 * Math.round(objRtn.numMultiPages/25);
} else if (objRtn.numMultiPages > 50 ) {
     var rounded_value = 50 * Math.round(objRtn.numMultiPages/50);
}...
```

etc. etc.

Comment: Then you may check the value range for upper values